# JavaScript getElementById the short syntax is working. Is it OK to use it?

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id=demo1></div>
    <button onclick=demo()>this is button</button>
}
```

and this is my JavaScript code:

```
function demo(){
  demo1.innerHTML="this is good syntax";
}
```

and this is a link that show how its work perfect... Please check the link  before you say that this syntax will not work.

https://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/QgEeOr

My question is why to ever use `document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML` when I can use just `demo1.innerHTML`?

Comment: Can you show me a working example where `demo.innerHTML="some text"` works?

Comment: I thing the second version includes: `var demo = document.getElementById("demo")` before

Comment: @YuvalPruss Then they're be the same, no?

Comment: `demo.innerHTML = "some text"` shouldn't work unless you have previously defined `demo` as a DOM object. Basically, what you are doing is calling the method `innerHTML` on an object which holds said method.

Comment: @j08691 Yes. But it's make sense- without this line, He will get an error.

Comment: https://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/QgEeOr                                                       u are welcome to see this syntax is working...i I really appreciate if u can change the negative vots

Comment: @ThomasValadez it will work. if there is only one element associated with that particular id on the entire dom. It's called 'named access'

Comment: @karthick just tested 'named access'. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is called 'named access'. Elements with 'name' or 'id' attributes are directly appended as property to the dom. You can even access the element by using window object window['demo1']. So it's possible to select element in this way if an element has an id or name that is unique in the document.

Caveat:

What if you have markup like this.

```
<div id=demo1></div>
<input name="demo1"/>
<button onclick=demo()>this is button</button>
```

https://codepen.io/pen/VWKqdv

The markup is valid because you don't have duplicate id's. But the way the named access works is it associates 'id' and 'name' together. So in this case you wont be able to select the element by named access, because 'demo1' will be associated with both 'div' and 'img' and it will return an array. In order to avoid this problem we use document.getElementById()

Named access :
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 0):

```
demo.innerHTML="some text"
```

wont work you need to define "demo" as a DOM first, check the line below

```
var demo = document.getElementById("demo")
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/QgEeOr                                                             
 u are welcome to see this syntax is working...i I really appreciate if u can change the negative vots

Comment: the syntax is working because (demo) is already defined as a DOM element in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

This is a new syntax, and although it's working, it's better and safer to use

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=
```